# Jquery cookie function not finding null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie, js-cookie

I have a button that when clicked should delete a cookie, call a function that collects a value from a textbox and save it as the new cookie value.

The problem I'm having is that after the button is clicked, the function is executing as if there was a value in the cookie.

I've logged the value of the cookie and it's showing null. Why isn't my function finding that the value is null?

```
//when new player is pressed
$('#BtnPlayAsNew').button().click(function () {
    $.cookie('name', null); //delete cookie

    $('#Result').hide();
    getUsername(); //call function 
});

function getUsername() {
    //get cookie 
    var cookie = $.cookie('name');
    //check value of cookie
    if (cookie == null || cookie == "") {
        $('#controls').hide();
        $('#NewUser').show();
        $('#BtnUser').click(function () {
            name=$('#tbUser').val();
            $.cookie('name', name,{path:'/' });
            $('#NewUser').hide();
            $('#controls').show();
        });
    }else{
        $('#NewUser').hide();
        $('#controls').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using an outdated version of jquery-cookie. Access https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases, get the first version and read the docs of the specific version/tag you want. As @Samurai pointed out, the `null` argument for removal was deprecated and removed months ago.

Answer (score 1):

`$.cookie('name', null);` does NOT remove the cookie, it assigns string `"null"` to it, you can check it by `console.log(cookie == "null");` which gives true. Instead you can use javascript's cookie with expiration date set on the past. So to set cookie null use this instead:

```
document.cookie = 'name=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
```